# No me funciona las varaibles en ejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ejs

Mi problema es que cuando quiero pasar una variable a EJS con esto:

```
res.render('index.ejs', {var1:"hola"} );
```

No me funciona porque me sale el "<" en rojo. Y ya tengo instalado el modulo, "npm i ejs"

[image: Me sale el "<" en rojo]

Comment: El código como texto por favor.

Comment: que parte del codigo?

Comment: No se usan capturas de pantalla para mostrar el código, todo el código que se ponga debe de ir como texto.

Comment: Podrías subir el código del index..js o server.js, quizás te falte indicarle al proyecto que estás utilizando ejs como motor de template.